# Inherited model with FK to base model overwrites base reference

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, multi-table

I have a situation where I have 2 models, with the second model (B) being a subclass of the first (A), and also having a (different) 1-to-1 reference to another instance of same parent model (A). The objective is to have some special cases of A linked to other instances of A's  in a new table, B's. For reasons I won't get into here, these need to be 2 different models (ie I can't add a nullable 1-to-1 reference field on A). This is illustrated below.

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class B(A):
    reference = models.OneToOneField(A)
```

However now when I try instantiate B with a reference to a different A, it doesn't work. Consider the following:

```
>>> a1 = A(name='a1')
>>> a1.save()
>>> b1 = B(name='b1', reference=a1)
>>> b1.save()
>>> b1.id
1
>>> b1.reference.id
1
```

Or alternatively:

```
>>> a1 = A(name='a1')
>>> a1.save()
>>> b1 = B(name='b1')
>>> b1.save()
>>> b1.reference = a1
>>> b1.save()
>>> b1.id
2
>>> b1.reference.id
2
```

Whereas what I would like here is for `b1.id` to equal 2 and `b1.reference.id` to equal 1 (referencing a1).

What is going on here? Why can't I have independent references to the base instance with the `ptr_id` and a different entry in the same table, in the `reference` field?

Comment: you can assign the value of `b1.refrence_id = 1`, but make sure that there is an instance in table `A` with id=1.

Comment: Hi @NalinDobhal, my apologies please see the edits, with the reference being a 1-to-1 association. It works with an FK, but I want to enforce 1-to-1. I can get it to work by changing the relationship to FK and enforcing uniqueness of the reference, but was wondering why it doesn't work with a OneToOneField